# Adjust TableViewRow height for length of string

Tags: titanium

Adjust TableViewRow height for length of string.

I have tableview, each row has has one message (1-500 letters).

But in this code , some are omitted and some are expanded.

Totally each row height is unstable.

Is there any good way to adjust the height of row according to message length.

```
var dateLabel =  Ti.UI.createLabel({
        top:'5%',left:'5%',
        text:dateLabel,
        color:"black",
        font:{fontSize: Ti.App.global.myFunc.makeFont(2),fontWeight:'bold'},
    });
var messageLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top:'15%',left:'5%',right:'5%',
    text:messageLabel,
    color:"black",
    font:{fontSize: Ti.App.global.myFunc.makeFont(2.8)},
});

var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({backgroundColor:'white',touchEnabled:false});
row.add(messageLabel);
row.add(dateLabel);

this.sectionNews.add(row);

this.table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    zIndex:15,

    backgroundColor:'white',
    data: [this.sectionNews],
    selectionStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify your table rowHeight as auto.

```
var myTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({height:400,rowHeight: 'auto', width: 312, top: 10,left:4, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',borderColor: '#C8C8C8',borderWidth:2, zIndex: -1});
```

you can also try below code while creating your tableRow as auto height

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
  height: 'auto'
});
```

version 2.0 +

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
  height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});
```